# Android hamburgermenu shouldn't have padding on the start left side

Tags: android, appbar

I'm having padding to the left off my hamburger menu, how can I remove it?

[image]

Here is the xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:translationZ="4dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonHamburger"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"

            <-- tried these 3 properties: -->
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="?bookmarkBarVisibility"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Here is the hamburger icon:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z"
      android:fillColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the Toolbar:

```
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```